# About Eucalyptus Virtualization Support

Tags: cpu, virtualization, vt-x

I am having hp 540 notebook with processor core 2 duo. I have installed CLC,CC,SC and Walrus runs fine when I try to run NC, I get error "Not virtualization enabled" means my laptop does not support virtualization. I got it.

Then,
In my college, there is Dell desktop PC having processor Core 2 Duo. But it has virtualization enbled.So I get confused. How same thing has different effects.

So my questions are

1. Which thing is essential for Virtualization??
2. What should I upgrade in my Laptop Processor or buy a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, If you want to deploy a cloud you have to carefully design your hardware. But as per your issue is concerned, the processor with VT technology should be used, until and unless you change this you cannot move further.... but i think you can even use VMware to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably point you at the [ubuntu UEC install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/PackageInstall) that suggests that VT-X is a prerequisite. Unfortunately, VT-X support on core 2 systems is a bit... haphazard, and you will want to check.

cat /proc/cpuinfo will give you information on your processor - you want to look for a line that says 'vmx' under flags.

I'd note not all virtualisation methods need vt-x - the approaches vmware and virtualbox work fine without it, and i suspect kvm should work as well. Unfortunately, swapping a processor of a different type is non-trivial, and finding a processor that works will need a lot of research. For a single vm node these approacges are probably better.